# Python reading Excel spreadsheet, creating multiple lists according to variables and conditions

Tags: python, excel, list

Hi there’s an Excel spreadsheet showing Product ID and Location, like below.

[image]

I want to list **all** the locations of each product ID **in sequence** with no duplication.

For example:

**53424 has Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix.**

56224 has Samarinda, Boise. Seoul.
etc.

What's the best way to achieve it with Python?

I can only read the cells in the spreadsheet but have no idea what’s good to proceed.

Thank you.

```
the_file = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\excel file.xlsx")
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

for row_index in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    product_id = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    location = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of Python's [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function to take away the duplicates as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
import xlrd

the_file = xlrd.open_workbook(r"excel file.xlsx")
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
products = defaultdict(list)

for row_index in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
    products[int(the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value)].append(the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value)

for product, v in sorted(products.items()):
    print "{} has {}.".format(product, ', '.join(k for k, g in groupby(v)))
```

This uses a `defaultlist()` with a dictionary to build your products. So each key in the dictionary holds your product ID and the contents is automatically a list of the matching entries. Finally the `groupby()` is used to read out each raw value and only give you one entry for the cases where there are consecutive identically values. Finally the list this produces is joined together with commas between them.

Comment: marvelous! thank you for your help. it seems it takes one more step to remove the continuous duplication (to have only one left) in each output. like the "Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix." instead of "Phoenix, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix."

Comment: The current version of the script should do that. i.e. it now uses groupby()

Comment: you are such a genius!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `dictionary` to store the data from excel and then traverse it according to product ID.

So, following code should help you out -

```
the_file = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\excel file.xlsx")
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

dataset = dict()

for row_index in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    product_id = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    location = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value
    if product_id in dataset:
        dataset[product_id].append(location)
    else:
        dataset[product_id] = [location]


for product_id in sorted(dataset.keys()):
    print "{0} has {1}.".format(product_id, ", ".join(dataset[product_id]))
```

Above will preserve the order of locations as per product_id (in sequence).

Comment: thank you for the help! however I need all the locations in sequence - like 53424 has "Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix, Matsuyama, Phoenix." not only "Matsuyama, Yanai"...

Comment: thank you for your help again. it seems it takes one more step to remove the continuous duplication (to have only one left) in each output.

Comment: If you only want to remove contiguous duplication (one-immediately-after-another) then you can use a variable to store previous line value and compare with the current one. If current one is exactly the same, you ignore adding the current values to the dataset. After all operations in the for loop, update the previous value variable with current value.

Comment: you help is very important for our learning. unfortunately I can only choose one for the answer, hope you don't mind. wish you a great day.